# Send parameter in redirectToRoute and Get It in the controller

Tags: php, symfony

I attempt to send a parameter in the redirection but the get in the controller return `null` :

Redirection :

```
    public function taskInUser(User $user): Response
    {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('task_add', ['user' => $user]);
    }
```

In the Controller:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/add", name="task_add")
     *
     */
    public function addAction(User $user = null): Response
    {
        dump($user);die();
        ...
    }
```

I attempt also that:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/add", name="task_add")
     *
     */
    public function addAction(Request $request): Response
    {
        dump($request->query->get('equipment');die();
        ...
    }
```

And It didn't work. I receive `null` in the controller but I checked and it send a good value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't add the parameter on your route declaration ?
Look here :

https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#route-parameters

You can use User id as int :

```
    /**
     * @Route("/add/{user_id}", name="add_user")
     */
     public function addAction(int $user_id)
```

or use ParamConverter to convert id to User without use Repository function.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#parameter-conversion

Comment: It generates an error because `user` is an object not a string

Comment: Yes it could be a solution but I want to receive all the `user` object

Comment: You can retreive User object with UserRepository, or use ParamConverter to get User object. See the links in my answer